# How to iterate through an xml path string (table rows -- tr[1], tr[2], tr[3]...) using Python?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, web-scraping

I have this html xml path:

```
"//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"
```

It has to be processed as a string by my find_element() algorithm
but I need to iterate up at tr[2] (eg, tr[2], tr[3], tr[4]...) so that my webscraping algorithm can expand a clickable button in a html table.

What are some strategies / implementations to accomplish this?

(I'm using the Selenium python library for the webscraper)

Comment: Check with the given (n) number of answers below , and let us know the status.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to loop through it then ,

Just make your xpath dynamic like this :

I am assuming you have 5 rows.

```
for i in range(5):
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr['"+i+"']/td[1]").click()
```

Or using WebDriverWait, it would be :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

for i in range(5): 
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr['"+i+"']/td[1]"))).click()
```

Note that, in case you will have to imports these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get collection of all desired elements (rows) using below code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="example"]/tbody//tr/td[1]");
```

Then you can iterate over collection of elements and do the desired operation.